# Which is the best ESRI ArcGIS component library to use with GWT?

Tags: gwt, dojo, arcgis, openlayers, esri

We are currently designing a GIS intranet application using GWT and ESRI ArcGIS. We are looking at 2 client side Javascript libraries:

1. [The ESRI Javascript API](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/)
2. [Open Layers](http://openlayers.org/)

The library will have to support [fused and non fused map caching](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.2/dotNet/manager/publishing/static_map_svcs.htm) as well as some layers that are dynamic. [Open Layers GWT integration](http://xircles.codehaus.org/projects/gwt-openlayers) exists but the ESRI library is based on [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/).

I'm looking for information and advice on where the gotchas will be for either approach.

Comment: It's always boggled me as to why they chose Dojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using ArcGIS, go with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. I think there are a lot more people out there using ArcGIS Server fused/non-fused map caches + ArcGIS API for JS than ArcGIS Server + OpenLayers so you'll have an easier time finding samples that are applicable to what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with Dojo as ESRI is already built on that one. It has great way of creating widgets and relatively good documentation. a lot of can be found at their forums (though these are now closed for posting new questions -> use stackoverflow instead or their mailing list)

here is the link that might be helpful to you
[javascript libraries comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks)

Comment: The ESRI forums are definitely not closed. There are new posts there daily:  http://forums.esri.com/forums.asp?c=158&s=2396#2396

Comment: We already did the front end in Dojo as a prototype and it wasn't pretty. GWT offers us a much better fit in terms of the style of application that the users want.

Comment: @swingley: I meant the dojo forums are somewhat closed. not esri forums

Answer (score 0):

GWT is perfect to structure big one-page application. So I'm developing a wrapper for the Javascript library.

http://github.com/lukefx/EsriGwt

It's in a super early state...I'm searching for someone who wants to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have picked up the lukefx's GWT project, retooled many of the 'under the hood' components. I started a new project here: [gwt-esri](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-esri/)